# Not able to navigate to loginpage on click in Asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i am doing sample regarding asp.net mvc 4 login page,here i have created home page and on click of link i should navigate to login page.Here the issue is on click of login link i am getting error page i am not able to login.below is the code i have used

UserLoginPage

```
@model EmployeeAppraisalform.LogindataTable
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border:1px solid red">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.PasswordFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    }
    @section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Homecontroller

```
public ActionResult Homepage()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UserLoginpage(LogindataTable u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // this is check validity
    {
        using (OnlineAppraisalEntities dc = new OnlineAppraisalEntities())
        {
            var v = dc.LogindataTables.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(u.Username) &&        a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                Session["LogedUserID"] = v.UserID.ToString();
                Session["LogedUserFullname"] = v.FullName.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("UserAfterLogin");
            }
        }
    }
    return View(u);
}

public ActionResult UserAfterLogin()
{
    if (Session["LogedUserID"] != null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
  <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Banking", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">

                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Homepage", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "UserLoginpage", "Home")</li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: You have not shown your `UserLoginpage()` GET method

Comment: @Stephen Muecke where should i use it?

Comment: You cannot navigate to a method marked `[HttpPost]` - you need to add a GET method - `public ActionResult UserLoginpage() { return View(new LogindataTable()); }`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke but why now on click of Login button i am not able to login its showing error

Comment: Because your form posts back to a method named `Login` which you don't have either (stop this dreadful naming that you have :). And I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials

Comment: @Stephen Muecke i got it ,thanks for concern